# Does a precessing spin in constant magnetic field change the field somehow?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrons, quantum-spin, precession

If an electron enters a magnetic field along the lines of the magnetic induction it spin starts to preccess. Suppose the field was made by a coil (toroid). What changes happen in the field - current - momentum of the coil?

Comment: Yes, that's what happens in an MRI machine, chemical NMR instruments with protons and other nuclei and with electrons in YIG oscillators: an external field excites the spins and their response is being measured (with the same coil or a different one).

Comment: What I found on MRI is "Pulses of radio waves are used to excite the nuclear spin energy transition"(Wiki). So you have a signal after the spin is irradiated by EM wave. What I have in mind with the question above is before irradiation (no irradiation) - just the spin rotating. Does this action of the magnet on the spin cause some changes in the current of coil itself?

Comment: Before the radio pulses the spins are in thermodynamic equilibrium with the environment, i.e. there is no net signal.

Comment: @CuriousOne What I mean is pure vacuum (no environment). So you think the magnetic field affects the electron (forcing its spin to preccess), but the electron itself does not affect the electrons in the coil which have created the field? Something is not according to common sense.

Comment: No, of course not. Both affect each other, but unless we supply energy to get the system out of thermodynamic equilibrium, the net effect is zero. That's the result of statistics, not a lack of back-reaction.

Comment: I don't understand what thermodynamics is here involved. This is a single spin. And as you say there is an effect on the coil, what is it?

Comment: Thermodynamics is always involved, we just like to avoid its effects, when possible. In case of macroscopic spin systems coupling to coils it's not possible (unless one makes the coils really small and goes cryogenic) since we can only observe the average of a very large number of spins. One can, of course, also do single spin ODMR experiments, which amplify the very small energy gaps of a single spin in a magnetic field into a much higher energy photon. With a coil and a macroscopic spin ensemble we get to detect a precessing magnetic field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40845/discussion-between-mercury-and-curiousone).

Comment: Yes, there will be an induced voltage and current. There was an old book called "Experimental pulse nuclear magnetic resonance: a nuts and bolts approach" by Fukushima, I believe, which took a very hands on (i.e. hardware!) approach to the field. If you want to learn "how it's done" and develop a simple but working intuition for what's going on in such an experiment, the book might be handy. Warning... I haven't looked at it in decades, so it may not be as good as it looked, back then.

Answer (score 0):

I have been an MRI technologist for 30 years and the electron has never come into the equations needed, even at the 7 tesla field strength. The spin characteristics of the hydrogen proton are  will line up parallel or anti-parallel to the magnetic and a cancellation of charges will leave you with the NMV ( net magnetic vector).

Comment: the question is not so specific to electron but the spin itself. Here the electron is regarded as a carrier of spin.